# Getting parts of date

Tags: javascript

I have a Web application that gets data from a DB, including `Datetime` fields.

I need to extract the year and month from a datetime field.

I added the following test code to print into the console:

```
        var aaa ;
        var bbb ;

        for (var i = 0 ; i < l_Data_List_Tempo.Body.length ; i++) {

            aaa = l_Data_List_Tempo.Body[i][l_Due_Date_Column]             ;
            bbb = Date.parse(aaa) ;

            console.log("Original : " + aaa           ) ;
            console.log("Converted: " + bbb.toString()) ;

            try {
                console.log("Year follows 1:")
                console.log("Value: " + date.getFullYear(l_Data_List_Tempo.Body[i][l_Due_Date_Column]))

            } catch (e) { }

            try {
                console.log("Year follows 2:")
                console.log("Value: " + date.getFullYear(bbb))

            } catch (e) { }

            try {
                console.log("Year follows 3:")
                console.log("Value: " + date(l_Data_List_Tempo.Body[i][l_Due_Date_Column]).getFullYear())

            } catch (e) { }

            try {
                console.log("Year follows 4:")
                console.log("Value: " + date(bbb).getFullYear())

            } catch (e) { }
  :
  :
```

The result in the console is:

> ```
> Original : 2016-08-09 00:00:00
> Converted: 1470690000000
> Year follows 1:
> Year follows 2:
> Year follows 3:
> Year follows 4:
> ```

As can be seen, the commands `console.log("Value: "..` all trigger errors.

How can I get from the original variable (i.e. `l_Data_List_Tempo.Body[i][l_Due_Date_Column]`) something lie **`2017-03`** (for March 2017)?

Comment: `date` is undefined

Comment: Ooopsss!!! Thanks @JohanKarlsson. It is `Date`. Still, same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set your bbb into the Date function and get the month or year

```js
   
var date = new Date(1470690000000);  // this will be bbb.toString()
var year = date.getFullYear();
var month = ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2)

var result = year + "-" + month;
console.log(result);
```

**updated**

I replaced
`date.getMonth()`

for
`("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2)`

Comment: BINGO!!! Thank you Marco. One more question: Is there any simple way to get the month number in two digits, like `03` for March?

Comment: I just updated the code

Comment: Nice!!! Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

1. There is no *date* object. [getFullYear](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getFullYear) is a function of a date object.
2. [Date.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) returns the string representation of the date, and not a date object.

You can use the [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) constructor to build a new date object based on your date string, and then use [getFullYear](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getFullYear) and [getMonth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth) functions of the date object to get the year and month for that date.

Something like this would work:

```js
var date = new Date("2016-08-09 00:00:00");
// in your case it will be this line
// var date = new Date(l_Data_List_Tempo.Body[i][l_Due_Date_Column]);
console.log("Year: " + date.getFullYear());
console.log("Month: " + (date.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, "0")); // zero-based
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using it incorrectly

```
var date = Date.parse(l_Data_List_Tempo.Body[i][l_Due_Date_Column]);
console.log(date.getFullYear())
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how to do it:

```js
var aaa = new Date("2016-08-09 00:00:00");
var year = aaa.getFullYear();
var month = aaa.getMonth();
console.log("Year is: " + year + "\nMonth is: " + month);
```